# htaccess to list directory files no longer works after Concrete 5 installation on 1and1

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, concrete5

I am working on an old website built on a Linux package hosted on http://1and1.com.

The site has many directories and subdirectories. For numerous, various subdirectories throughout the site where we wished to list the directory contents, we created .htaccess files with a single line: "Options +Indexes"

Recently, Concrete5 was installed. Since the installation, all subdirectories with the .htaccess file no longer list the directory contents. Instead, Concrete 5 now serves the following error page:

"Page Not Found
No page could be found at this address. 
Back to Home."

I have searched the web to find a way to enable the .htaccess files with the Concrete5 installation to no avail. Note that we do NOT want all subdirectories to list directory contents, only those that have the .htaccess file. We also prefer not to install any additional Concrete5 Add-ons.

How do we enable the .htaccess files to coexist with the Concrete5 installation? Is there a switch or configuration file that needs to be modified within Concrete5 to allow the .htaccess file to do its job?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Concrete5 has any problem with htaccess in general. I would guess the problem is elsewhere.
I am not too clear on what you have right now. Was Concrete5 installed alongside those other directories? Inside one of them?

Also to be clear you say the problem is double:
1- files are not listed anymore in directories with the htaccess
2- Concrete5 keeps not finding any page
Is that correct?

Comment: The problem definitely lays with Concrete5. Concrete5 was installed in a specific subdirectory. All subdirectories under the Concrete5 subdirectory now no longer list the filenames despite having an .htaccess file. All other directories outside of the Concrete5 subdirectory list filenames just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an htaccess file at the root of the Concrete5 directory? Maybe a directive there creates the problem.

Really all C5 does, if asked, is add a directive to the root htaccess file to get pretty urls. That might be the problem. Other than that, I don't see how it could block htaccess directives.

Also the fact that C5 itself can't load a page makes me lean towards the "rogue htaccess file theory"

Comment: There is no htaccess file at the root Concrete5 directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well then I can only think of 2 things:

1. make sure pretty url is not enabled in C5
2. your C5 folders need to be chmoded to allow file listing as usually
   they are restricted.